# Finding unknown value.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have the function $u=\frac{x^2y^2}{x+y}$. I'm asked to determine the value in terms of $u$
of the following operation:
$x\frac{du}{dx} + y\frac{du}{dy} = ?$ Clarification: express your answer in terms of $u$ as for example: $7u$.

The answer to this question is '$3u$', but I do not know the process to find this value since the variables '$x$' and '$y$' have no assigned values.

All I have so far are the respective first order derivatives of $x$ and $y$, I have tried to substitute the derivatives of $x$ and $y$ in the equation $x\frac{du}{dx} + y\frac{du}{dy}$, but I can't get the result $3u$.

First derivative of $u$ with respect to $x$: $\frac{y^2x(x+2y)}{(x+y)^2}$

First derivative of $u$ with respect to $y$: $ \frac{x^2y(y+2x)}{(x+y)^2}$

Comment: Please, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for better formula rendering.

Comment: everything is correct. proceed with your calculation and you will get the result

Comment: @Ripi2 formatting formulas as code (fixed font) is a good alternative if one is not familiar with Mathjax

Comment: @miracle173 Yes, I agree. But in this case formulas where ambiguous. And if you plan to continue in this SE, some time you'll have to use MathJax.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function#Euler's_homogeneous_function_theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have got the right approach. Let me continue it for you

$$\frac{du}{dx}= \frac {y^2x(x+2y)}{(x+y)^2} \;\;\; \text{and} \;\;\; \frac{du}{dy}= \frac {x^2y(2x+y)}{(x+y)^2}$$

So,
$$x\frac{du}{dx} + y \frac{du}{dy}= \frac {xy^2x(x+2y)}{(x+y)^2} + \frac {yx^2y(2x+y)}{(x+y)^2}$$

$$=\; \frac {x^2y^2(x+2y)}{(x+y)^2} + \frac {x^2y^2(2x+y)}{(x+y)^2}$$
$$=\; u\frac {x+2y}{x+y} + u\frac {2x+y}{x+y}$$
$$=\; u \left( \frac {x+2y+2x+y}{x+y} \right) \;=\;u \frac{3x+3y}{x+y} \;=\;u \frac{3(x+y)}{x+y} \;=3u$$

Comment: formatting text as variables is a bad alternative if one is familiar with Mathjax